# Sum values after each interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, foreach

I have three arrays. Two array contains values to be calculated and another array is to get the interval year. I am facing issue while looping the array in given interval for given number if years. If the year is 10 and interval is 2. I have to increment the value for every 2 year in 10 years.

Code:

```js
A = [3249, 789]; // 3249 is for 2 years and 789 is for 3 years
B = [162483, 39483];
C = [{ "s.no": 1, "year": 2 }, { "s.no": 2, "year": 3 }]
n = 10; //no of years
var temp = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    var sum = B.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    C.forEach((element, n) => {
        if (element.year == temp) {
            sum = sum + a[n];
            temp = 1;
        }
        else {
            temp = temp + 1;
        }
    })
}
```

My issue is the temp is working only if I have only one year.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your algorithm is not easy to understand when reading the code. It is hard to help without knowing what the program is supposed to do. Maybe you should start by writing down a description of what your input is and what you want to achieve and add it to your question.